# Effect is not run (not even once) when state setter is called in function body

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Please help me understand how state setter works when called inside a function body

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  const flagRef = useRef(true);

  if (flagRef.current) setState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    flagRef.current = false;
  });

  return 'MyComponent';
}
```

Running this code will result in infinite re-rendering. According to the React documentation, it says The setState function is used to update the state. It accepts a new state value and enqueues a re-render of the component.. I interpret this as the next render will be enqueued and run after the current render finishes, including running the effect. However, the effect is never run at all, not even once, and the chain of re-rendering is happening forever without any bailing out even the code is updating the same state again, i.e. 1

Please help me understand the internal working of this piece of code.

Comment: The `useEffect()` hook takes a second optional argument which is an array of dependencies. This will cause a rerender of the component should any of the dependencies change. Could you provide more context on the component?

Comment: There is nothing special about this component. The `useEffect` in the code snippet is purposedly written without depenrency list so that it will run after every render. However, it didn't run at all.

Answer (score 0):

A working version of your code (snippet below):

**NOTE:** You can also add a dependency array to your `useEffect` in order to determine when that effect should run.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  
  console.log('MyComponent is rendering...');
  
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);
  const flagRef = React.useRef(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect is running...');
    if (flagRef.current) {
      console.log('flagRef is true... will call setState(1) and turn flag to false...');
      setState(1);
      flagRef.current = false;
    }
    else {
      console.log('flagRef is false... I will not do anything');    
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>My state: {state}</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```